# Unable to run code on riscv rocket chip when FPU is disabled

Tags: riscv

I wrote a c code and compiled it with riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc and ran it on the rocket chip instantiated on a zedboard using the proxy kernel and front end server(./fesvr-zynq pk ).

The same binary works on the zedboard when the fpu is enabled from configs.scala but the binary just doesn't execute when the fpu is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to compile the code differently. When you remove the FPU, Rocket is no longer RV64IMAFD (RV64G), but now only RV64IMA. You will need to recompile your code, riscv-pk, and ricsv-fesvr all for RV64IMA.